# Algorithm to extract legal citations in a document

Tags: python, regex, nlp, spacy, spacy-3

I want to train a machine learning model to learn and extract legal citation patterns in a text document. What is the best algorithm can I use?  My training data sample set of legal citations that looks like,

```
    sample set: 
    Brill v. Guardian Life Ins. Co. of America, 142 N.J. 520, 529 (1995)
    Della v. Guard Lifal Ins. Co. of SA, 142 N.J. 420, 549 (2011)
    Heljon Mgmt. Corp. v. DiLeo, 55 N.J. Super. 306, 312-13 (No Citations. This was 
    extracted from NJ Sup..)
    Ocean Cape Hotel Corp. v. Masefield Corp., 63 N.J. Super. 369, 383 (App. Div. 1960)
```

The citations training sample were extracted from documents using regex code,

```
r'(?:[A-Z]\w*\.? )+v\. .*?\d{4}\)'
```

I have tried spaCy entity matching but that is not working (I bet my code is not perfect). My code

```
import re
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

from spacy.matcher import Matcher
m_tool = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

doc = open(file='text1.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8').read()
#print(text)

doc = nlp(doc)
#print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])


p1 = [{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'LOWER': 'v'}, {'IS_PUNCT': True}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}]
p2 = [{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'LOWER': 'v'}, {'IS_PUNCT': True}, 
{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}]
p3 = [{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'LOWER': 'v'}, {'IS_PUNCT': True}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, 
{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'},]
p4 = [{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'LOWER': 'v'}, {'IS_PUNCT': True}, 
{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}]
p5 = [{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'LOWER': 'v'}, 
{'IS_PUNCT': True}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}]
p6 = [{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'LOWER': 'v'}, {'IS_PUNCT': True}, 
{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}]
p7 = [{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'LOWER': 'v'}, {'IS_PUNCT': True}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, 
{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}]
p8 = [{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'LOWER': 'v'}, 
{'IS_PUNCT': True}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}]
p9 = [{'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'LOWER': 'v'}, 
{'IS_PUNCT': True}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}, {'IS_TITLE': 'NN'}]
p10 = [{'label': 'PERSON'}]
P11 = [{'label': 'ORG'}, {'label': 'PERSON'}]
p12 = [{'label': 'PERSON'}, {'label': 'ORG'}]
p13 = [{'label': 'ORG'}, {'label': 'ORG'}, {'label': 'ORG'}, {'label': 'ORG'}]

m_tool.add('QBF', None, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13)

phrase_matches = m_tool(doc)
print(phrase_matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

Philip, I would look at classification to provide you with a more robust method(s) of extraction, beyond what you will be able to get from pattern matching. I really like the process flows now supported by Prodigy (part of explosion that created spaCy), for developing Active Learning flows to support the continuous improvement often required for data extraction.

- Build pattern rules and use those rules along with Sense2Vec to generate a good working set of patterns/annotations.
- Use the pattern rules to generate a model, that can be used to learn contexts for the supplied patterns.
- Use prodigy (or core spaCy) to create additional labels and updates to the model results to fine-tune and optimize the extractions.

An additional address Example using NLTK: This is a similar scenario to yours.
https://onethinglab.com/2018/03/05/extracting-addresses-from-text/

Patterns and regex just won't be robust enough for your use case.